# DocumentDb SELECT with sub object

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

My `team` object is as below and I'm trying to get only the members using a `select` statement. The problem I'm having is that I'm getting the results but the position is getting lost because it's not mapping to my POCO object because the result is "flat".

My `team` object looks like this:

```
{
  id: 123,
  name: "My Team",
  members: [
     {
       id: 789,
       name: "John Smith",
       position: 
       {
          id: 444,
          name: "Manager"
       }
     },
     {
       id: 987,
       name: "Jane Doe",
       position: 
       {
          id: 222,
          name: "Director"
       }
     }
  ]
}
```

My `select` statement looks like this:

```
SELECT m.id, m.name, m.position.id as positionId, m.position.name as positionName
FROM Teams t
JOIN m IN t.members
WHERE t.id = 123
```

So, when I run the select statement above, I'm getting what I show below and the object shape of a member doesn't match my POCO object so the position information disappears.

```
[
  {
    id: 789,
    name: "John Smith",
    positionId: 444,
    positionName: "Manager"
  },
  {
    id: 987,
    name: "Jane Doe",
    positionId: 222,
    positionName: "Director"
  }
```

]

My C# POCO object's shape matches the JSON object. So I have a Position object inside my Member object.

How do I get members in the exact shape they are in the database?

UPDATE:
I changed my `select` statement to the following and it worked nicely. It now automatically gives me the exact shape of my POCO object.

```
SELECT m.id, m.name, m.position
FROM Teams t
JOIN m IN t.members
WHERE t.id = 123
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I'd prefer to use a simple DTO and map it to your POCO afterwards (either manually or using automapper). Seems reasonable to separate DB controlled format from what your app uses.

Another option would be to look at http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/CustomJsonConverter.htm but I find it more complex than a specialized DTO and a mapping.

Comment: I already use DAO objects and handle mapping between DAL and the domain. I always read DAO objects from DocumentDb so that I don't have to worry about getting the shapes right. Anyway, I found the solution and updated the original post. It was an obvious solution. I don't know why I didn't think of it sooner.